# What should I write to resize my webbpage to view on Ipod and Iphone?

Tags: php

Im trying to add some code when I run my code to detect a Ipod and Iphone, but I can not finde any information on the webb.

```
$iPod = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPod");
$iPhone = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
$iPad = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPad");
if(stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android") && stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"mobile"))
{
    $Android = true;
}
else if(stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android"))
{
    $Android = false;
    $AndroidTablet = true;
}
else
{
    $Android = false;
    $AndroidTablet = false;
}
$webOS = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"webOS");
$BlackBerry = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"BlackBerry");
$RimTablet= stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"RIM Tablet");


//do something with this information
if( $iPod || $iPhone )
{
    // What code should It be here.
}
```

Comment: You should do this with CSS and or JS

Comment: @Paul Ok, can you post some links about that?

Comment: google.com look for CSS Media queries. Also research responsive design